# How to access the error present for an entity in 3.X?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Because I have to create a 'file' input field manually, I need to display errors by myself.

So, after a submit, errors are present for the fields site.image_0 and site.image_1:

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Sitedescription) {

    ...
    ,
    'properties' => [
        'site' => object(App\Model\Entity\Site) {

            ...
            ,
            'properties' => [
                ...
                ,
                'image_0' => null,
                'image_1' => null,
                ...
                ,

            ],
            'dirty' => [
                'image_0' => true
                'image_1' => true
            ],
            'original' => [],
            'virtual' => [],
            'errors' => [
                'image_0' => [
                    '_empty' => 'Un fichier image jpg ou png doit Ãªtre Ãªtre spÃ©cifiÃ©.'
                ],
                'image_1' => [
                    '_empty' => 'Un fichier image jpg ou png doit Ãªtre Ãªtre spÃ©cifiÃ©.'
                ]
            ],
            'repository' => 'Sites'

        },
    ...

}
```

So how can I access to the messages present in errors[] to display it?

I tried to detect errors by `$this->Form->isFieldError('site.image_1')` and it returns false.

And `$this->Form->error('site.image_1')` returns nothing.

I create the form like that:

```
 <?= $this->Form->create($sitedescription, ['type' => 'file'])?>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="dropzone" data-image="<?=(!empty($sitedescription->site->image_0) ? "/img/".$sitedescription->site->imgfile0 : null)?>" data-ajax="false" data-ghost="false" data-originalsize="false" data-canvas="true" data-width="500" data-height="500" style="width: 100%;">
           <input type="file" name="imgfile0"/>
          </div>
        </div>

        ...
```

Comment: What does your form create call look like?

Comment: Looks good to me, that's exactly how you would do it. Maybe start with updating your CakePHP dependency.